# All-sides resize of borderless NSWindow in Lion

Tags: cocoa, nswindow, osx-lion

In Lion, the standard resize method for windows changed from the lower-right corner to all sides, with an invisible area to click and drag. I have a custom borderless window, similar to the App Store, on which I would like to have this resize behavior (currently, I have a custom resizer view in the bottom right). I searched for "10.7" in the `NSWindow` documentation, but none of the newly available messages seem to suggest a way to enable this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know which object is responsible for setting it up, but `NSWindow` now has tracking areas in the corners and edges (Open Quartz Debug and check "Show tracking rectangles" to see what I mean).  You could emulate this behavior without too much difficulty -- it's basic geometry.

Comment: This definitely would work, but it turns out it's a lot simpler and a  bad mistake on my part. I was constructing my window with `NSBorderlessWindowMask`, which was all that was necessary on SL, since all other behavior was custom. On Lion, since I'm using the system-provided resizing, I needed to add `NSResizableWindowMask`. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Another note for any future Googlers: make sure you only enable the resizable mask on Lion, or you'll get the standard window border on Snow Leopard as well as your custom one.

Comment: @Nate what's your preferred way to ensure that it's on Lion?  It can't be an availability test -- the mask has been available for a long time already!

Comment: A simple way to do it that I've seen but haven't tried is `NSClassFromString(@"NSPopover") != nil`. Personally, I use `Gestalt(gestaltSystemVersionMinor, &minor)`, then `minor > 6` (where `minor` is an `SInt32`).